# I want my loop to run until the result of the equation equals the previous result

Tags: while-loop, fortran

I am writing a code in FORTRAN to calculate the position of the planets. I need to solve Kepler's equation using newtons numerical method and I am having trouble with my loop. The code is shown below. I can compile it with no error messages, but it wont run. It just gets stuck in a forever loop. I want the loop to run until E(i) and the following result are equal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
do while (E(i)/=E(i+1))
    E(1)=M
    E(i+1)=E(i)-((M-E(i)+(p*sin(E(i))))/((p*cos(E(i)))-1))
end do
```

Also, how do i define the variable 'E' at the beginning of my program. I currently have this but the '11' is only because I originally had my loop run 10 times. If I don't specify the number of times I want the loop to run, how do i define the variable?

```
double precision :: E(11)
```

Comment: the primary problem here is you never set `i`

Answer (score 3):

I did not check if your convergence implementation is correct, but you definitely do not want to check for exact equality. You must allow for some inexactness, because floating point calculations are inexact

```
     (abs(E(i)-E(i+1))<eps)
```

where `eps` is some small number.

As @agentp suggests you don't change `i`, so you always work with 2 values `E(i)` and `E(i+1)` (`i` being whatever you set it before the loop). You do not use any other elements of your array.

For the array which can have any length, depending on your need, you could theoretically use

```
     double precision, allocatable :: E(:)
```

but you probably do not want to use an array at all and you just want two scalar values

```
 double precision :: E1, E2

 E1 = M
 do
    E2 = E1 - ((M-E1+(p*sin(E1))) / ((p*cos(E1))-1))

    if (abs(E1-E2) < eps) exit
    E1 = E2
 end do
```

Note that the kind notation (`real(....)`) is preferable in new code instead of the old `double precision`.